# Bundler misses gems on Mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have problems loading gems with bundler. Happens only in my mac environment. The gem cannot be found via bundler, but when I install the gem globally via `gem install #{gem}` it works.

I suppose this is something environment specific, but I am not sure how to debug it. I have the same versions of ruby, ruby-install and chruby and bundler on a Ubuntu box, but it works just fine.

So far I had this problem with the gems spring-comands-rspec and rack-cors.

Broken environment (Mac):

```
OS: Darwin nb-mjacobus2 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Bundler: 1.15.4
ruby-install: 0.6.1
chruby: 0.3.9
ruby: ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

### Exposing the error:

Gemfile

```
group :development do
  # ...
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  # ...
end
```

Running tests

```
./bin/rspec spec/controller/some_controller_spec.rb:8
/$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- spring-commands-rspec (LoadError)
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.spring.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:29:in `<module:Spring>'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/server.rb:9:in `call'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<main>'
```

Manually installing the gem solves the problem....

```
gem install spring-commands-rspec
Fetching: spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4
Parsing documentation for spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4
Installing ri documentation for spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4
Done installing documentation for spring-commands-rspec after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

... BUT I get this warnings:

```
./bin/rspec spec/pattern_library_controller_spec.rb
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      minitest (~> 5.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      minitest (~> 5.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Running via Spring preloader in process 53164
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

Randomized with seed 5284

SomeController
  should respond with a success status code (2xx)

Finished in 0.13193 seconds (files took 0.66951 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 5284
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the gems were installed inside inside vendor/bundle, but not all of them. Removing `rm -rf .bundle vendor/bundle && bundle install` did it.

The content of .bundle/config was:

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:related"
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; Try to move `spring-commands-rspec` to `test` group in `Gemfile`:

```
group :development
  # ...
  # ...
end
group :test do
# ...
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end
```

OR `group :development, :test do` if you need the gem not only for tests.

**In short**: There is `Environment` concept, when you run something in Rails. Loaded gems are also depend on it through `Gemfile` - `Bundler` loads common gems and gems from corresponding groups. The *default* environment is **development**, but `rspec` uses **test** one. So, gems from group *development* are not loaded when you run `rspec ...` if they are not listed in group *test* also.

**UPDATE**:
It seems you have set up your app *in server mode*(may be you get install command from deploy script). Because it's pretty typical to have `.bundle` dir and `vendor/bundle` when deploy Rails app on the *staging/production* server(i.e. gems are installed locally with app).
But in that case you `.bundle/config` should include `BUNDLE_PATH` at least:

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "1"
BUNDLE_PATH: "./vendor/bundle"
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:test"
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "true"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was actually the bundle config (as I answered above). The gems were in the correct group. In fact, I also had  tried outside of  the groups, with rack-cors.

Comment: @Marcelo Replied in post.